# How to customize right side of NavigatorIOS?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to make my navigation bar (NavigatorIOS component) like Whatsapp's bar. There must be profile picture and a call button next to it on the right side of bar.

How can I do this? Which property should I use?

Or should I use Navigator component for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can achieve this in different ways, you can use rn Navigator and build your own toolbar (left button, title, right button).

so you can provide a template for the toolbar, something like this

```
let routeMapper = {
  LeftButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
    { return (<Text>Cancel</Text>); },
  RightButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
        { return (<Text>Done</Text>); },
  Title: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
        { return (<Text>Awesome Nav Bar</Text>); },
}
```

**Notice that you can provide a template for Right button section.**

then you need to pass routeMapper to Navigator component

```
navigationBar={
    <Navigator.NavigationBar
        routeMapper={routeMapper}
        style={{backgroundColor: 'gray'}}
    />
 }
```

You can also try **react-native-router-flux**, probably will increase complexity but it's so worth.

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Comment: Thank you, but I want it to seem like native navigator component just like NavigatorIOS, so do I have to add style to NavigationBar manually?

Comment: no, you can have default iOS styles  without using `style` property , that property is available for you to customize the toolbar..

Comment: I have this without style property: http://imgur.com/Rk8ZUnC
It is not default ios style :(

Comment: i think you're right, its not default iOS styles, you will need need to provide your own custom styles.

Comment: check react-native-router-flux for routing Scenes, they provide the navbar that you want as default, im using at the moment.